# Why is the Linq-to-Objects sum of a sequence of nullables itself nullable?

Tags: c#, linq, sum, nullable, base-class-library

As usual, `int?` means `System.Nullable<int>` (or `` System.Nullable`1[System.Int32] ``).

Suppose you have an in-memory `IEnumerable<int?>` (such as a `List<int?>` for example), let us call it `seq`; then you can find its sum with:

```
var seqSum = seq.Sum();
```

Of course this goes to the extension method overload [`int? IEnumerable<int?>.Sum()` (documentation)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb156065.aspx) which is really a static method on `System.Linq.Enumerable`.

However, the method never returns `null`, **so why is the return type declared as `Nullable<>`?** Even in cases where `seq` is an empty collection or more generally a collection all of whose elements are the `null` value of type `int?`, the `Sum` method in question still returns zero, not `null`.

This is evident from the documentation, but also from the System.Core.dll source code:

```
public static int? Sum(this IEnumerable<int?> source) { 
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source"); 
    int sum = 0; 
    checked { 
        foreach (int? v in source) { 
            if (v != null) sum += v.GetValueOrDefault(); 
        } 
    } 
    return sum; 
}
```

Note that there is only one `return` statement and its *expression* `sum` has type `int` (which will then implicitly be converted to `int?` by a wrapping).

It seems wasteful to always wrap the return value. (The caller could always do the wrapping implicitly on his side if desired.)

Besides, this return type may lead the caller into writing code such as `if (!seqSum.HasValue) { /* logic to handle this */ }` which will in reality be unreachable (a fact which the C# compiler cannot know of).

**So why is this return parameter not simply declared as `int` with no nullable?**

I wonder if there is any benefit of having the same return type as [`int? IQueryable<int?>.Sum()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339977.aspx) (in `System.Linq.Queryable` class). This latter method may return `null` in practice if there are LINQ providers (maybe LINQ to SQL?) that implement it so.

Comment: I'm guessing it's to continue with the format of  `Sum` returning the same type that you are summing.  Ultimately only one of the C# designers can answer this though.

Comment: The parity with `Queryable` is the only thing I can think of, too. You are right to say that it never returns  `null`: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Sum.cs

Comment: @HimBromBeere there is no overload of the form `Sum<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)`; the *generic* APIs all also take a *selector* of the form `Func<T, int>` etc

Comment: Better question, why check for `null` and then use `GeValueOrDefault`?

Comment: @HimBromBeere  generic operators aren't a thing, though; there  is no good way of doing maths with `T`, short of  external libs  that do crazy things

Comment: Well, you can always use: `seq.Sum(i => i.GetValueOrDefault())`

Comment: @juharr: because [`GetValueOrDefault`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/nullable.cs,8b928034cfee7d43,references) is more efficient than [`Value`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/nullable.cs,7b38d1fa76071c95,references), it doesn't need to check if there is a value, it just returns the field `value`.

Comment: Anyway: what should `Sum` return if all entries are actually `null`? Zero was inappropriate here as well, I guess. However the current code does return zero.

Comment: There is no evaluation like "null + null = null". So why would not it be "null + null = 0" :D

Comment: @HimBromBeere it returns 0

Comment: @MarcGravell I know (OP already mentions). But is this meaningfull? I doubt that even `null + 1` makes any sense. Consider calculating the average now, which would be 0.5 when only having two elements. I guess 1 would be more accurate here, as the collection has only one entry having any *data*, but that´s my opinion.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I'd say *yes*, but that either interpretation is valid-ish as long as it is  fully defined. The  problem with saying that the sum of nulls is null is that it then follows logically that the sum of anything that includes a null is null, which is not what people usually intend when doing a sum.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I wonder if that means the `null` check is more efficient that using `HasValue` as well.

Comment: @juharr `==null` / `!=null` on `Nullable<T>` is just language tricks; it compiles to a `.HasValue` test

Comment: @MarcGravell That's what I thought.  I guess it's just a preference thing then.

Comment: @MarcGravell "the sum of anything that includes a null is null" But then we know for sure that there was some data missing in our collection, which I´d prefer somehow instead of ignoring the fact that we miss some values.

Comment: It probably boils down to some method returning default(int).  Which is 0.

Comment: What answer do you expect, so they return int? ... If it is big deal for you create extension method which will return (int)col.Sum();.

Comment: @HimBromBeere and others: That is just the way they chose it; they skip all `null` values. Of course if you had done iterated ___lifted___ `+`, as in the example `var seqSum2 = seq.Aggregate((int?)0, (x, y) => x + y);` (or just doing `+=` of nullables in a `foreach` loop), then `seqSum2` could very easily end up as `null`. But as soon as we decide for the convention of skipping all null values, the result can never become null, because we also have the convention that the empty sum is zero.

Comment: Although I like the question it fairly isn´t answerable by the community but only by Microsoft. So unless none of them posts an answer here I guess this question should be closed as ... huuum... maybe opinion-based?

Answer (score 4):

Several comments have mentioned that this isn't really answerable (or only opinion based without official response). I won't argue that. However, one can still perform analysis on available code and form a strong enough theory. Mine is simply that this is a an existing MS pattern.

If you look through the rest of `System.Linq.Enumerable`, in particular the math related functions, you start to see a pattern of having the tendency to return the same type as the input parameter, *unless* the return has a specific reason to be of a different type.

See the following functions:

`Max()`:

```
public static int Max(this IEnumerable<int> source);
public static int? Max(this IEnumerable<int?> source);
public static long Max(this IEnumerable<long> source);
public static long? Max(this IEnumerable<long?> source);
```

`Min()`:

```
public static int Min(this IEnumerable<int> source);
public static int? Min(this IEnumerable<int?> source);
public static long Min(this IEnumerable<long> source);
public static long? Min(this IEnumerable<long?> source);
```

`Sum()`:

```
public static int Sum(this IEnumerable<int> source);
public static int? Sum(this IEnumerable<int?> source);
public static long Sum(this IEnumerable<long> source);
public static long? Sum(this IEnumerable<long?> source);
```

For the exception to the rule, take a look at `Average`...

```
public static double Average(this IEnumerable<int> source);
public static double? Average(this IEnumerable<int?> source);
```

You can see that it still retains the `Nullable<T>` type, however the return type must be altered to a suitable type to support the result that averaging integers together yields.

When you look further into `Average` though, you see the following:

```
public static float Average(this IEnumerable<float> source);
public static float? Average(this IEnumerable<float?> source);
```

Again, back to the default pattern of returning the same type as the original incoming type.

Now that we see this pattern here, let's see if we see this anywhere else... let's take a look at `System.Math` since we are on that subject.

Again, here we see the same pattern of using the same return type:

```
public static int Abs(int value);
public static long Abs(long value);

public static int Max(int val1, int val2);
public static long Max(long val1, long val2);
```

I'll mention it again, this is what amounts to an "opinion answer". I have looked for any MS best practices or language specification information that might hint at this being a language pattern for MS to back up my analysis, but I could not find anything. That being said, if you look at various places in the .Net core libraries, especially the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace, you will see that unless there is specific reason, the return type matches the collection type.

I see no reason for that rule to be deviated from when it comes to `Nullable<T>` types.

Comment: I acknowledge the observation. There may be a tendency to prefer returning the same "type". But also note that things like `Max`, `Min` and `Average` that are undefined for empty (count-0) sources, will actually return `null` in that case. But only with a sequence of nullables; those methods will explode with an exception in the non-nullable case, on an empty input sequence.

Comment: That is the behavior I would expect. Given that the original (non-nullable) `Max` (etc...) throws an exception if the list is empty. My expectation would be to either throw an exception like the original, or as is the case here, return a nulled `Nullable<T>`. I expect that because in normal situations operations performed on a null set have no value, hence are null themselves. `Sum` is a bit different in that you are starting with a value of 0 and performing mathematical operations using the contents of a set. If the set is empty, you still have 0. If the set contains a list of nulls, 0 still.

Comment: Put another way, what is the Maximum value of an empty set? Now, what is the value of an empty group added together?